# Property 'submitter' does not exist on type 'Event'

Tags: typescript, types

Banging my head against the wall on this one...

given this function

```js
const handleFormSubmitByButton = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const submitter  = event.nativeEvent.submitter;
  
  console.log(submitter?.value)
};
```

and markup

```html
<form onSubmit={handleFormSubmitByButton}>
  <button type="submit" name="test" value="test">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Why am I keep getting `Property 'submitter' does not exist on type 'Event'.`?

I tried to use `SyntheticEvent` from `React` like so: `SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement, SubmitEvent>`

This yields `submitter` being okay but then complaining about `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

As a last result, know it won't work I did also try to type cast on the declaration of `submitter`. :S

TS version in project is `4.9.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add guard clauses:

```
const handleFormSubmitByButton = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!(event.nativeEvent instanceof SubmitEvent)) return;

    const submitter = event.nativeEvent.submitter;

    if (!(submitter instanceof HTMLInputElement)) return;

    console.log(submitter.value); // ok
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBi0IAogG5IB28AvnAGZQQhwBEUqGLA3AFA9oQKAZ3gALFBQAmAGySEoIAMoBXAEYhgMAEIBPLcpgxBcALxwAFEnJUAXASJlKMADwAJACoBZADLySskCcAPgBKUyDcHjhouCsnADowdmsYABEkOhRlaRhzEN4omOA6CwBCSxT4ihQYYHJHKjhgYRgJNCQIEpV1TQaYELD2GGUoCgKYuAEWuCE1DUMkKFNYyura+srZnoWocaKS83Kt+ZhFppa2jpKPHwBJCjADYgCnAbghkbG+CamhCFl4tIIABzczHTSnKDxUgoaTKJD5OAAeiRcAgAGseNReEA)

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Is this solution considered a/the best practice?